# Swift TableView pass selected Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two `TablewViewControllers`: `ListTableViewController` which holds my list of items and a `SortTableViewController` where I store sort options for the ListTableView. I need to find a way to highlight the active (if user clicked a sort option) sort option (`Cell`) when the `SortTableViewController` loads.Any ideas how to do this?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MCP0.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you need the sort selection to persist, you can try this.
Use NSUserDefaults to store the selected row index (this assumes your sort options list is fixed)

```
    class SortTableViewController : UITableViewController {

        let selectedRowIdx = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("PLACE_YOUR_KEY_HERE")

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = // your implementation here

            if indexPath.row == selectedRowIdx {
                cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            }
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(indexPath.row, forKey: "PLACE_YOUR_KEY_HERE")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You ca try this

```
class SortTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var highlightedIndexPath: NSIndexPath? //TODO: populate this

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = //TODO: populate this
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = indexPath == highlightedIndexPath ? .redColor() : .blackColor()
        return cell
    }
}
```